# Open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Consider

$$\begin{align}D&:=\left\{(x,y): e^x > \sin(y)\cos(x)\right\}\\
A&:=\left\{(x,y): x^7-\sin(y^7) \geq \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}\right\}
\end{align}$$
Show that D is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, while A is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

How do I show these things?
Thank you!

Comment: What work have you done? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $D = f^{-1}(V)$ where $V = (0,\infty)$ and $f(x,y) = e^x - \sin(y)\cos(x)$. You can make a similar argument for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A set $U$ is open if and only if for all $x\in U$ there exists an open ball centered at $x$ contained in $U$. From this definition it must be easy to show that $D$ is open. For $A$ is suffices to prove that its complement is open.